# How do I programmatically update field values in a Redux form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux

I’m new to React and Redux. I have a redux form with several fields. In my Redux DevTools I can see my form and all its “values” and watch input changes. After the user has input all required data, clicking the “submit” button updates the Redux state with the new data via an action. All of this is working.

While the user is inputting data and prior to submitting changes, I have a requirement that when the user makes changes to a certain field, I need to change the displayed value of another field. More specifically prior to updating the form’s state, when a user inputs a change to field “A” I need to retrieve the form’s displayed value of field “B”, do a calculation and then display the result in field “C”.

Is there a way to access my Redux form’s displayed values”? How do I programmatically update a displayed Redux form field value?

Comment: Simply bind all field A, B, and C to your redux states, when you input A, change the B, C value programmatically is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in Redux DevTools, you can see the actions that are dispatched by redux-form:

[image: Redux DevTools screenshot]

You can actually dispatch those actions yourself to set values programmatically:

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';
// snip...
change('form-name', 'field-name', 'new-value');
```

You can view all redux-form action creators here: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/